# Specify source language, if the default_locale is not english

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-translator

I am working on a website for a French customer.
My `translations.yml` looks like this:

```
framework:
    default_locale: en
    translator:
        default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/translations'
        fallbacks:
            - fr
```

I write everything in english, and then run this command:

```
php bin/console translation:update --force fr
```

It generates `.xlf`, files with these parameters:

```
source-language="en" target-language="fr"
```

It works as expected.

I would like to make the login page French as well. That page is visited, when the user is not logged in yet, so `default_locale` is used.

I changed `default_locale` to `fr` and `fallbacks` to `en`.

The login page is displayed in French as expected, but now the `translation:update` script is broken. If I run it, the resulting translation files have these incorrect parameters:

```
source-language="fr" target-language="fr"
```

How is it possible to use a different source language for translations and default locale for pages, where the user is not logged in? Or is it possible to use the locale from the user agent in that case?

Comment: did you try to force translation to french ? $translator->setLocale('fr_FR');

Comment: In `app/config/config.yml` tried with below one?
`framework:
    default_locale: fr`

Answer (score 0):

If you use locale in URL (see [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/locale.html#the-locale-and-the-url)), you can force the parameter `locale` like this in your PHP code:

```
/**
 * Login page in French by default
 * Except if the user specifies the locale in the URL
 * 
 * @Route("/", name="login_default", locale="fr")
 * @Route("/{_locale}", name="login_default_lang")
 */
public function index()
{
   return $this->render('login_page.html');
}
```

For other pages in English by default:

```
/**
 * Other page in English by default
 * Except if the user specifies the locale in the URL
 * 
 * @Route("/", name="other_default", locale="en")
 * @Route("/{_locale}", name="other_default_lang")
 */
public function index()
{
   return $this->render('other_page.html');
}
```